# Comment transposer ou traduire « Lord willing and the creek don't rise » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions, formulation-idiomatique

> I think *with the grace of God*, the goodwill of the neighbor and *the
> creek not rising*, as the old saying goes, I think we may be able to
> get that to 1.5 million a day, rather than 1 million a day.
>
> [ Le président de États-Unis, Joe Biden, au sujet de la [campagne de
> vaccination](https://www.cnn.com/2021/01/25/politics/biden-vaccine-distribution/index.html) ]

Il s'agit d'une variante d'une locution combinant [*the creek don't rise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_creek_don%27t_rise) à [*Lord/God willing*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/God_willing#English) sans nécessairement ajouter plus de sens : « [Lord willing and the creek don't rise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lord_willing_and_the_creek_don%27t_rise) ». Comment transpose-t-on la locution dans le discours du président puis couramment et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 1):

Il ne semble pas exister une phrase toute faite. On doit cependant pouvoir trouver bon nombre de combinaisons qui seront des traductions satisfaisantes. En voici deux qui me viennent à l'esprit.

- Si Dieu le veut et si le ciel ne nous tombe pas sur la tête…
- Si Dieu le veut et si le monde continue à tourner…

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Dans les deux cas l'expression reste dans le domaine d'un humour léger, et les idées qui amènent cet effet sont également outrée ;  je ne vois pas une bien grande différence de registre, et l'une ou l'autre doit convenir dans une communication de routine par un personnage officiel.

Comment: D'accord, merci !